# Any issue with allowing CORS on an oauth2 endpoint

Tags: openid-connect

I am tempted to let my OpenID Connect/Oauth2 OP to accept [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) request on an oauth2 endpoint after checking that client id and its allowed origin match.

This way a RP would be able to get a response directly without using redirect_uri or a postmessage relay or a web storage relay madness.

Any foreseen issues?

Comment: How would that work? I mean how would you protect the "secret"?

Comment: You have not provided enough information for anyone to give you an accurate answer.  The only advice i can give you is to read the OAuth RFCs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are restricting the output of CORS headers for trusted client IDs and origin combinations only then this should not open up your site to any CSRF attack vectors.